# how to display all the records in the database inside a html table body section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server

[image: This is how the data are being fetched from database]

**How do I display the data inside a table in body section of the html page**

This is my code which I have tried so far

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Sample</title>

<script language="javascript" src="bop/scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="cw/scripts/common.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#but_submit").click(function(e) {
        getstandings()
    });
});

function getstandings()
{
    var url = "sample.aspx";
    var data = 
    {
        object:"getstandings",
        action:"hello"
    };

    getItem(url, data, afterGetInformations);
}

function afterGetInformations(data)
{
    console.log(data);

    var res = $.parseJSON(data).Result
    if (res && typeof res === "object" && res != null)
    {
        status = parseInt(res.RetCode);
        if(status == -1)
        {
            message2("#msg2", res.ErrMsg);
            return;
        }
    }

    var objs = $.parseJSON(data).Item;

    if (objs && typeof objs === "object" && objs != null)
    {
        var str = "<div>"+objs[0].club_name+";"+objs[0].mp+";"+objs[0].win+";"+objs[0].draw+";"+objs[0].lose+";"+objs[0].gf+";"+objs[0].ga+";"+objs[0].gd+";"+objs[0].pts+"</div>";

        $("#but_submit").after(str);
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="but_submit"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Data is being fetched from the database. The problem is how to display it in a table.

[image: actual expected outcome]

Comment: create a table manually / with javascript. and then add the data with this reference 'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
It will create a table consiting of all the records with each row indicating an object

```
if (objs && typeof objs === "object" && objs != null)
        {
           var tbl='<table id="mytable"><tr> <th>ID</th><th>ClubName</th><th>MP</th><th>Win</th><th>Draw</th><th>Lose</th><th>Gf</th><th>Ga</th><th>Gd</th><th>Pts</th></tr>';

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
  var tb1+="<tr><td>"+objs[0].id+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].club_name+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].mp+"</td> 
        <td>"+objs[0].win+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].draw+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].lose+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].gf+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].ga+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].gd+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].pts+"</td></tr>";

}
$("#but_submit").after(str);
    }
```

let me know if you need any help in this regard. I would be glad to help you. Thanks

Comment: it show error here `var tbl='<table id="mytable"><tr> <th>ID</th><th>ClubName</th><th>MP</th><th>Win</th><th>Draw</th><th>Lose</th><th>Gf</th><th>Ga</th><th>Gd</th><th>Pts</th></tr>";`

Comment: @ThanesJagarnathan I've modified the answer. there was double quotation in the end of statement insted of single quotation.

Comment: @ThanesJagarnathan let me know if you need any other help in this regard. And if you find the answer useful, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick mark(grey colored) on the left of the answer. And also upvote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
     if (objs && typeof objs === "object" && objs != null)
      {
 var str = "
   <table>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>ClubName</th>
        <th>MP</th>
        <th>Win</th>
        <th>Draw</th>
        <th>Lose</th>
        <th>Gf</th>
        <th>Ga</th>
        <th>Gd</th>
        <th>Pts</th>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>"+objs[0].id+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].club_name+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].mp+"</td> 
        <td>"+objs[0].win+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].draw+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].lose+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].gf+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].ga+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].gd+"</td>
        <td>"+objs[0].pts+"</td>
        </tr>
   </table>";

                $("#but_submit").after(str);
            }
```